# Using Laravel QueryBuilder "when" and add a custom value to Query result

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

What I'm trying to do is simple :
- When a calculated distance depending on users latitude and longitude (on DB) is higher than an int, we remove the current user from result by adding a where
- When that distance isn't higher, we add a custom value to the returned result

This can be easily done using a foreach AFTER the query is executed :

```
foreach($search as $key => $value){
            if(distance($value->latitude,$value->longitude,$user->latitude,$user->longitude,"K") > $distance) {
                unset($search[$key]);
            } else {
            $search[$key]->distance = $calculatedDistance
        }
        }
```

The cons of this way is that in case we have a large database, it will consume a lot of memory and time, as we do twice what should be done directly in query.

What I need to do is to make this executed on the query itself. What I don't know how to do is :
- Adding a custom value to the query directly when query is executed, and to do the distance calculation inside a when in the query, without using a foreach but directly getting the current raw value to compare with.

What I'm doing now :

```
->when($distance > 0, function ($query) use($distance, $longitude, $latitude){
                     $query->where(function ($subQuery) use ($longitude, $latitude,$distance) {
                        $cDistance = distance((int)$subQuery->value('latitude'),
                            (int)$subQuery->value('longitude'),
                            $latitude,
                            $longitude,
                            "K");
                         $subQuery->when(($cDistance > $distance),
                            function ($subQuery){
                                $subQuery->where('users.id', '<>', (int)$subQuery->value('id'));
                            },function ($subQuery) use ($cDistance) {
                                 $subQuery->value((string)$cDistance.' as distance');
                            }
                        );
                    });
```

`$subQuery->value('something')` is only testing with the first raw of the query, and not doing this for all rows.
`$subQuery->value((string)$cDistance.' as distance');` is returning an error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   '84.354917445764' in 'field list' (SQL: select `84`.`354917445764` as
>   `distance` from `users` limit 1)

Comment: **->value($column_name)** just bring the value of the **$column_name**. paste the method content to try help you

Comment: which method content ? What I need is simply adding a value to the query result like $user = [username => myname] I need to add age of 5 so that result become $user = [username=>myname,age=5]

Comment: I know. mean by the method the beginning of `->when()` function

Comment: it is a simply query with a select and where ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sqlDistance = DB::raw('ROUND ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(' . $latitude . ') ) 
                            * cos( radians( doctor_profile.latitude ) ) 
                            * cos( radians( doctor_profile.longitude ) 
                            - radians(' . $longitude . ') ) 
                            + sin( radians(' . $latitude . ') ) 
                            * sin( radians( doctor_profile.latitude ) ) ) )');
```

Inside the query :

```
->selectRaw("{$sqlDistance} AS distance")
            ->when($distance > 0, function ($query) use ($distance,$sqlDistance){
                    $query->havingRaw('{$sqlDistance} <= ?', [$distance]);
                })
```